# Cannot resample time series data, TypeError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to resample this data downloaded from quandl but keep have a `TypeError` thrown my way even though it looks to be of the `datetime64[ns]` type.

I have tried running `pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])` to ensure it of the datetime type with no luck.

```
df = pd.read_pickle('data1')
print(df.Close.head())
df = df.reset_index()
df = df[['Date', 'Close']]
print(df.Date.head())
df = df.resample('W').mean

Date
2004-08-19    100.335
2004-08-20    108.310
2004-08-23    109.400
2004-08-24    104.870
2004-08-25    106.000
Name: Close, dtype: float64
0   2004-08-19
1   2004-08-20
2   2004-08-23
3   2004-08-24
4   2004-08-25
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/raymond.devries/PycharmProjects/untitled2/datatry.py", line 15, in <module>
    df = df.resample('W').mean
  File "/Users/raymond.devries/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 8155, in resample
    base=base, key=on, level=level)
  File "/Users/raymond.devries/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/resample.py", line 1250, in resample
    return tg._get_resampler(obj, kind=kind)
  File "/Users/raymond.devries/PycharmProjects/untitled2/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/resample.py", line 1380, in _get_resampler
    "but got an instance of %r" % type(ax).__name__)
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not realize that the date time data times needed to be set as the index. The resample function reads the index of the data frame. The index of data frame was already set to a date time index, therefore I did not need to run `df = df.reset_index()` and by doing so I turned my index into a range object.

Working code:

```
df = pd.read_pickle('data1')
df = df[['Close']]
df = df.resample('W').mean()
print(df.head())
```

Output:

```
               Close
Date                
2004-08-22  104.3225
2004-08-29  106.8660
2004-09-05  101.2300
2004-09-12  102.8800
2004-09-19  112.4900

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly stated that resample is only valid for date index format on the other hand you got range index like a dataframe first convert the index from range to date type data,drop the date column  then do resample it will work.